# Defining Javascript type as array of literals from another Object property values

Tags: arrays, flowtype

```js
const familyTypes = [
  { id: 'COUPLE', name: 'Couple' },
  { id: 'SINGLE_LADY', name: 'Single lady' },
  { id: 'SINGLE_GENTLEMAN', name: 'Single gentleman' }
];

type State = {
  familyType?: (what can I put here?)
};
```

Is there a statement that would set `familyType` above to an array of the literal values `'COUPLE' | 'SINGLE_LADY' | 'SINGLE_GENTLEMAN'` programatically?

Note: this is using Flow in React; the idea is that a statement like this would later throw a static type error:

`var state: { familyType: 'SOMETHING_ELSE' }`

Comment: You can use [`familyTypes.map(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Start with defining the `familyType: []`, and then write a loop that adds the values programatically.

Comment: `type State`? If this question is actually about a TypeScript declaration, and not a JS array value, then I suppose no it's not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that I'm defining a Flow type in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a combination of [`$ElementType`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-elementtype) and [`$ReadOnly`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly) to get the job done. Element type is the interesting one here:

> `$ElementType<T, K>` is the type that represents the type of every element inside an array, tuple or object type T, that matches the given key type `K`.
>   ...
>   [W]hen using `$ElementType<T, K>`, `K` is allowed to be any type, as long as that type exists on the keys of `T`.

Here it is in action:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#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-W2uOxQBmacd4hzksLlLMTgACQAtOxL35gH9+OsEZsgA))

```
type familyTypes = [
  { id: 'COUPLE', name: 'Couple' },
  { id: 'SINGLE_LADY', name: 'Single lady' },
  { id: 'SINGLE_GENTLEMAN', name: 'Single gentleman' }
];

// We want the type of elements indexed by a number
type familyObjs = $ElementType<familyTypes, number>

// We're only going to read from this type (this
// prevents problems with variance caused if we
// were to write to the value)
type familyObjsReadOnly = $ReadOnly<familyObjs>

// The type of the thing stored at the 'id' property
type idType = $ElementType<familyObjsReadOnly, 'id'>

type State = {
  familyType: idType
};

const state1: State = { familyType: 'COUPLE' }
const state2: State = { familyType: 'SINGLE_LADY' }
const state3: State = { familyType: 'UH-OH' } // Error
```

Go ahead and plug in `familyObjs` in place of `familyObjsReadOnly` in that last `$ElementType` if you want to see why we need to use `$ReadOnly`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to return an array of ids from familytype

```js
const familyTypes = [
  { id: 'COUPLE', name: 'Couple' },
  { id: 'SINGLE_LADY', name: 'Single lady' },
  { id: 'SINGLE_GENTLEMAN', name: 'Single gentleman' }
];

var State = {
  familyType:  familyTypes.map(type => type.id)
};
console.log(State)
```

Comment: Is this answer valid even after I've clarified that I was talking about static typing?